# Hide Repeated Iteration in Django Template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am using Django. In my template i am using for loop but i don't need to print the same date which is already printed. so my code is-

```
{% for applicant in applicants %}

<div class="row">
    <div  class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2">
            <div  class="col-xs-12 application_slot_list">
                <h5>{{ applicant.created_on|date }}</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-10 candidate_list_application">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 list-title">
                    <h4>{{ applicant.employee }}<small class="pull-right"><button class="btn btn-link">Download CV</button></small></h4>
                </div>
```

So here i am trying to print two things, employee and date but i don't want to print repeated date. So is there any way to do this. I want to do this only in template not in views.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`{% ifchanged %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged) tag:

> Check if a value has changed from the last iteration of a loop.

```
{% for applicant in applicants %}
    <div class="row">
        <div  class="col-xs-12">
            {% ifchanged %}
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2">
                    <div  class="col-xs-12 application_slot_list">
                        <h5>{{ applicant.created_on|date }}</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endifchanged %}
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-10 candidate_list_application">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 list-title">
                        <h4>{{ applicant.employee }}<small class="pull-right"><button class="btn btn-link">Download CV</button></small></h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This would work only provided the queryset is ordered by `created_on`

Comment: @karthikr "Checks its own rendered contents against its previous state and only displays the content if it has changed.". This not a technical requirement, common reason begs for that.

Comment: Agreed !. All I am saying it, it only checks for the previous iteration value, so there is no guarantee that the dates are not repeated !